# How to find the image of this function?

Tags: functions

I have been struggling with this math problem for a few days. I really need some help.

Find the image of $h : (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x) = 1/(x^2 + 8x)$ for $0 < x < 1$.

I know the answer is $(1/9, \infty)$, but I have no clue about how to prove it. In other problems, I can usually define a set $S$ to equal this interval and choose an element in that set and show it's in the image. Then choose am element in the image and show it's in the set. So, the image equals my set. But, I couldn't get that to work here.

As another attempt, I proved the function is strictly decreasing on $(0, 1)$, so it's injective. I couldn't get anywhere after that though.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac1{x^2+8x}=\frac{1}{(x+4)^2-16}
\end{align}

Hence if $0<x<1$, we have

$$4<x+4<5$$

$$4^2-16<(x+4)^2-16<5^2-16$$

$$0<(x+4)^2-16<9$$

$$\frac19<\frac1{(x+4)^2-16}$$

Comment: That is clever. What about the infinity part ?

Comment: $(x+4)^2-16$ can get arbitrarily small and positive, hence when we divide by $1$, it gets arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^2+8x$ is an increasing function which maps the interval $(0,1)$ onto $(0,9)$

Thus your function which is the reciprocal of $x^2+8x$ maps the interval $(0,1)$ to $(1/9,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $g\colon x \mapsto x^2+8x$ is increasing on $0 < x < 1$, you have $g(0)=0 < x^2+8x < 9=g(1)$ if $0<x<1$. But $g$ is also continuous, hence for $0 < x < 1$ it reaches all values between $0$ and $9$. So $h(x)= 1/g(x)$ reaches all values between $1/9$ and $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y$ be any number such that $y \in (1/9, \infty)$. Then the formula
$$x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{y} +16} -4 $$
will explicitely give you an $x\in (0,1)$ such that $h(x) = y$.